# Implementing observer pattern with Flow API

Tags: java

I need to process asynchronous tasks each time a double value is being updated.

At the beginning I was using SimpleDoubleProperty from java.fx.beans and attached every listeners but it seemed to have concurrency issues.

Since Observable is deprecated I checked the Flow API.

I implemented the stuff like that.

**ObservableDouble**

```
public class ObservableDouble implements Flow.Publisher<Double> {

    private final AtomicReference<Double> value =
        new AtomicReference<>(Double.MIN_VALUE);

    public double getValue() {
        return value.get();
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value.set(value);
    }

    public boolean isSet() {
        return value.get() != Double.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(Flow.Subscriber subscriber) {

    }
}
```

**ObserverDouble**

```
public class ObserverDouble implements Flow.Subscriber<Double> {
    private Consumer<Double> consumer;

    public void setConsumer(Consumer<Double> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription subscription) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Double item) {
        consumer.accept(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
    }
}
```

And I'm planning to use it like that

```
ObservableDouble observableDouble = new ObservableDouble();
ObserverDouble observerDouble = new ObserverDouble();
observerDouble.setConsumer(c -> {
    System.out.printf("\nDouble value has changed : %s.", c);
});
observableDouble.subscribe(observerDouble);
observableDouble.setValue(1.);
// Should print text
```

What to put in the #onSubcribe, #subscribe and other methods?

Does the usage of Consumer here is relevant?

Comment: Implementing `Publisher` is not exactly trivial. A publisher is responsible for managing its own subscribers. A subscriber is added to a publisher via `subscribe` and is removed when the `cancel` method of the subscriber's subscription is invoked. When a subscriber is registered, the publisher invokes its `onSubscribe` method with a subscription implementation. Then the publisher must invoke `onNext`, `onError`, and `onComplete` on registered subscribers when appropriate, taking into account if and when a subscriber requests more items via its subscription's `request` method.

Comment: Note it's the subscriber that's responsible for requesting items. And all this has to be thread-safe. Read the documentation of `Flow` and its nested interfaces for more information. There's also [`SubmissionPublisher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/SubmissionPublisher.html) that you can read about, look at the implementation of, or even use. But if you want to use "reactive streams", I suggest using an existing library, such as _RxJava_.

Comment: Yet your use case doesn't seem to need something as complex as `Flow` or _RxJava_, unless there's more to it than you've let on. You could just write your own class that does what you want. It doesn't have to conform to an existing interface.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I created a simple interface `public interface Observer<T> {
 void onChange(T item); }` and implemented it but it seems I can't implements generic interface in Java `implements Observer<Type1>, Observer<Type2>`. I will have to create an interface for each type.